# Search the document for text to remove more than the tag it's found in

Tags: javascript

Imagine you had html code like this:

```
<div id="2761421" class="..." data-attributionline="testtext wrote at..." data-created-at="1342689802000" data-updated-at="1342689802000" data-user-id="36847" >                             
  <div class="subject">    <strong>                                      
      <a name="2761421" href="#2761421">wee</a></strong>                             
  </div>                                             
  <div class="info">                                     
    <div class="author">      author:                                              
      <span class="name">        testtext         (                                             
        <a href="">we</a>)                                                                     
      </span>                                     
    </div>                                     
    <div class="date">      date:                                        
      <time datetime="dfgdf">dfgdfg                                      
      </time>                                     
    </div>                                
  </div>                             
  <hr style="clear: both;" />                             
  <div class="text gainlayout">        some text                            
  </div>                             
  <div class="foot gainlayout unselectable">                                     
    <span class="menuitem postmenuitem-report">                                      
      <a href="dfgdfg" data-remote="true" class="nav" data-confirm="dgdfg" rel="nofollow">cvbcvb</a>                                
    </span>        
  </div>                    
</div>
```

What would the javascript code look like that searches the whole document for parts where the div with data-attributionline= contains testtext to replace the whole cited div from start to finish with "Filtered"?

**or**

What would the javascript code look like that searches the whole document for

```
<span class="name">
```

where the name contains testtext to replace the whole div starting from

```
<div id="<someid>" class="..." data-attributionline="testtext<some text>" data-created-at="<somedate>" data-updated-at="<somedate>" data-user-id="<someid>" >
```

to the last div, ie

```
    </span>        
  </div>                    
</div>
```

with "Filtered"?

Comment: What quote? Can be be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole bunch of [attribute selectors](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#attribute-selectors) (see also [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)), that will match elements with attributes that start with or contain `testtext`.

In javascript, you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelector)[[`All`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)]`()` or a library function that supports those to get the elements, then [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) them.